# How can I check if any accounts were recently opened in my name

Tags: united-states, credit-card, bank-account, identity-theft, credit-rating-agency

Someone just tried to open a Paypal credit account in my name. I was able to get the account closed and the charges revoked, but now I need to make sure there is nothing else out there.

How can I check if there are any accounts that have recently been opened in my name? Can I contact the credit agencies and ask them for such a list? If so, how? I just tried with Equifax their maze of useless phone menus defeated me.

Comment: I know when I purchased a Equifax report it listed most of my accounts. The only way to work with Equifax is to use their site. The cheapest offering was fine for me. It may be a good start. Also to open a Paypal account in your name must take some identification of some sort, so perhaps change your credit card numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Short of calling every single bank and pay day loan lender on earth there's no way of knowing for sure.  There's no law requiring lenders to report to a reporting organization like Equifax, so it's possible that an account can be opened and you wouldn't know about it until many years down the line when a collection agency reports it.

Comment: Is there a way to at least get a list of the ones that did report? At least a start

Comment: www.annualcreditreport.com

Answer (score 1):

The standard advice to find out about accounts in your name is through your credit reports. [By US law, the credit reporting companies are required to offer one free credit report per 12 month period](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0155-free-credit-reports).

> The Fair Credit Reporting Act (FCRA) requires each of the nationwide credit reporting companies — Equifax, Experian, and TransUnion — to provide you with a free copy of your credit report, at your request, once every 12 months.

Make sure you use the authorized web site: https://www.annualcreditreport.com. There are unscrupulous copycats that charge you fees for your credit reports.

> Only one website is authorized to fill orders for the free annual credit report you are entitled to under law — annualcreditreport.com.